# how can I take advantage of creating multiple database users if I only have one login in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database

I created a web application in my local development machine. My system have 4 logins each one is associated with a different database user. Now that I am publishing my application I have the issue of my host company giving me only one login. I had antecipated this in my mind but I develped my site locally the way I thought be correct. I used different logins because I denied certain operations on some database objects, for example I denied a visitor to update a vendor's table, denied a visitor to execute the procedure that returns a vendor's registered products and etc. I would like to know if I can deploy my application with this level of security with one login only.

Comment: Can you not request more logins?  It isn't like they cost money...

Comment: I contacted them they said that is not possible.

Comment: One one hand, this seems really strange that they're only allowing one login.  But on the other hand, it also seems strange that you would even need multiple logins for a single web application.  It sounds like you're giving the user access to login directly to the database...  I can't think of a reason to have multiple logins from the application for database interaction.

Comment: I have four connnections in my web.confg file. When the user accesses my web site without a submitting a login I associate him with a string "visitor" and if him is authenticated I associante him with a string "vendor" and store it in session. then the user is going to performed some operation on my site that string is checked and passed to a method to acccess the respective connection string in the web.config file. Because I have permissions set for different users If a visitor try to do something nasty he won't. It's pretty neat.